# Integrating infinite-scroll with virtual-scroll

Tags: angular

I am planing to integrate ngx-infinite-scroll with angular 7 virtual scroll, in my angular application CLI version 7, virtual-scroll is working but infinite scroll is not working.

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/infinite-virtual-scroll-angular-cdk/

Answer (score 0):

ngx-infinite-scroll is also working but it's want a fixed height for apply infinite scroll on page.

Like:-

**page.component.html:-**

```
<div class="center" ngxInfiniteScroller strategy="scrollingToBottom"
    (onScrollDown)="onScroll()"
    [ngStyle]="{overflow: 'auto', height: pageHeight + 'px', 'background-color': '#f5f5f5'}">
</div>
```

**page.component.ts:-**

```
public pageHeight: any = screen.height;
```

**page.module.ts:-**

```
import { NgxInfiniteScrollerModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroller';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageComponent
  ],
imports: [       
    NgxInfiniteScrollerModule,
],
providers: [
]
})
export class PageModule {
}
```

Comment: Actually I was using ngx-infinite-scroll npm to build the infinite scroll. This was quite a good option, I never knew that virtual scroll has its own event , Thank you !!